# Error converting data type nvarchar to date in Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to load data in SQL Server database using a Python script. In this data the last column of my table is date in YYYYMMDD format. But while importing program gives following error:

```
pymssql.OperationalError: (8114, b'Error converting data type nvarchar to date.DB-Lib error message 20018
```

It is adding '\n' for each row. How can I avoid this and without changing the datatype in SQL load this data?

Comment: try calling rstrip() on the string before you convert it

Comment: I tried using that as well but its giving the same error and not allowing me to load the data in database.